# Update specific record in table with form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I built a database for a fleet of trucks. One of my forms allows the user to enter a new job that was done to a truck. One of these fields is 'kilomètres' (miles)

To be short, I want the 'Kilomètres' field in the 'new job' form to update the 'Kilomètres' field in the table but only for the specified vehicles.

In VBA I tried both of these (these codes are run with the click of a button):

```
UPDATE véhicules : infos particulières           ' (which is the table name)
SET Kilomètres = [Kilomètres]
WHERE [Véhicules] = Véhicules
```

OR something like this :

```
[Véhicules : infos particulièrs].Kilomètres = Kilomètres
```

but than I don't know how to refer to the specific record...

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
"UPDATE [Véhicules : infos particulières] SET Kilomètres = " & Me.txtKilomètres] & " WHERE [Véhicules] = " & Me.txtVéhicules
```

as SQL string in vba, if Véhicules is a number. else add qoutes.

`txtKilomètres` and `txtVéhicules` are the names of the controls of the form.

if vba-code is not inside the form, you have referer to the form by formname

Avoid accents and other special characters, use `_` instead of spaces

Comment: This solved my problem thanks a lot

The final code is 

DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE tbl_trucks_specific SET Kilometrage = " & Me.Kilometrage _
& " WHERE numAlexpress = " & "Véhicules")